# Show Checkbox Values In Alert Box

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, validation, checkbox

I'm working on an assignment and have hit a wall.

I'm trying to display the check box values for toppings in the alert box pop-up screen once submitted. The text box and radio values appear but check box returns a blank value.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

```js
<html>
<head>
<title>HTML and JavaScript</title>
<script>
function doClear()
{
 document.PizzaForm.customer.value ="";
 document.PizzaForm.address.value = "";
 document.PizzaForm.city.value = "";
 document.PizzaForm.state.value="";
 document.PizzaForm.zip.value="";
 document.PizzaForm.phone.value="";
 document.PizzaForm.email.value="";
 
 document.PizzaForm.sizes[0].checked = false;
 document.PizzaForm.sizes[1].checked = false;
 document.PizzaForm.sizes[2].checked = false;
 document.PizzaForm.sizes[3].checked = false;
 
 document.PizzaForm.toppings[0].checked = false;
 document.PizzaForm.toppings[1].checked = false;
 document.PizzaForm.toppings[2].checked = false;
 document.PizzaForm.toppings[3].checked = false;
 document.PizzaForm.toppings[4].checked = false;
 document.PizzaForm.toppings[5].checked = false;
 document.PizzaForm.toppings[6].checked = false;
 document.PizzaForm.toppings[7].checked = false;
 document.PizzaForm.toppings[8].checked = false;
 return;
}

function doSubmit()
{
 if(validateText() == true);
 if(validateRadio() == true);
 if(validateCheck() == true);
 
 alert("Name:" + " " + document.PizzaForm.customer.value + 
    '\n' + 
    "Address:" + " " + document.PizzaForm.address.value + 
    '\n' +
    "City:" + " " + document.PizzaForm.city.value +
    '\n' +
    "State:" + " " + document.PizzaForm.state.value +
    '\n' +
    "Zip:" + " " + document.PizzaForm.zip.value +
    '\n' +
    "Phone:" + " " + document.PizzaForm.phone.value +
    '\n' +
    "Email:" + " " + document.PizzaForm.email.value +
    '\n' +
    "Size:" + " " + document.PizzaForm.sizes.value +
    '\n' +
    "Toppings:" + " " + document.PizzaForm.toppings.value);
 return;
}
function validateText()
{
 var customer = document.PizzaForm.customer.value;
 if (customer.length == 0)
 {
  alert("Please enter your name.")
 }
 var address = document.PizzaForm.address.value;
 if (address.length == 0)
 {
  alert("Please enter an address.")
 }
 var city = document.PizzaForm.city.value;
 if (city.length == 0)
 {
  alert("Please enter a city.")
 }
 var state = document.PizzaForm.state.value;
 if (state.length == 0)
 {
  alert("Please enter a state.")
 }
 var zip = document.PizzaForm.zip.value;
 if (zip.length == 0)
 {
  alert("Please enter a zip code.")
 }
 var phone = document.PizzaForm.phone.value;
 if (phone.length == 0)
 {
  alert("Please enter a phone number.")
 }
 var email = document.PizzaForm.email.value;
     atpos = email.indexOf("@");
  dotpos = email.lastIndexOf(".");
 if (atpos < 1 || ( dotpos - atpos < 2 ))
 {
  alert("Please enter an email address.")
  return false;
 }
  return true;
}

function validateRadio()
{
 if (document.PizzaForm.sizes[0].checked) return true;
 if (document.PizzaForm.sizes[1].checked) return true;
 if (document.PizzaForm.sizes[2].checked) return true;
 if (document.PizzaForm.sizes[3].checked) return true;
 if (document.PizzaForm.sizes.value == false);
 {
  alert("Please choose a pizza size.");
 }
 return;
}

function validateCheck()
{
 if (document.PizzaForm.toppings[0].checked == false &&
  document.PizzaForm.toppings[1].checked == false &&
  document.PizzaForm.toppings[2].checked == false &&
  document.PizzaForm.toppings[3].checked == false &&
  document.PizzaForm.toppings[4].checked == false &&
  document.PizzaForm.toppings[5].checked == false &&
  document.PizzaForm.toppings[6].checked == false &&
  document.PizzaForm.toppings[7].checked == false &&
  document.PizzaForm.toppings[8].checked == false)
  {
   alert("Please pick a topping of your choice.");
  }
   return false;
   return true;
}

</script>
</head>

<body>
<form name="PizzaForm">
<h1>The JavaScript Pizza Parlor</h1>
<p>
<h4>Step 1: Enter your name, address, and phone number:</h4>
<font face ="Courier New">
Name: &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input name="customer" size="50" type="text"><br>
Address: <input name="address" size"50" type="text"><br>
City: &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input name="city" size="15" type="text">
State: <input name="state" size="2" type="TEXT">
Zip: <input name="zip" size="5" type="text"><br>
Phone: &nbsp;&nbsp;<input name="phone" size="50" type="text"><br>
Email: &nbsp;&nbsp;<input name="email" size="40" type="text"><br>
</font>
</p>
<p>
<h4>Step 2: Select the size of pizza you want:</h4>
<font face="Courier New">
<input name="sizes" type="radio" value="Small">Small
<input name="sizes" type="radio" value="Medium">Medium
<input name="sizes" type="radio" value="Large">Large
<input name="sizes" type="radio" value="Jumbo">Jumbo<br>
</font>
</p>
<p>
<h4>Step 3: Select the pizza toppings you want:</h4>
<font face="Courier New">
<input name="toppings" type="checkbox" value="Pepperoni">Pepperoni
<input name="toppings" type="checkbox" value="Canadian Bacon">Canadian Bacon
<input name="toppings" type="checkbox" value="Sausage">Sausage<br>
<input name="toppings" type="checkbox" value="Mushrooms">Mushrooms
<input name="toppings" type="checkbox" value="Pineapple">Pineapple
<input name="toppings" type="checkbox" value="Black Olives">Black Olives<br>
<input name="toppings" type="checkbox" value="Green Peppers">Green Peppers
<input name="toppings" type="checkbox" value="Extra Cheese">Extra Cheese
<input name="toppings" type="checkbox" value="None">None<br>
</font>
</p>
<input type="button" value="Submit Order" onClick="doSubmit()">
<input type="button" value="Clear Entries" onClick="doClear()">
</form>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You have so much unnecessary code and if conditions. I recommend you look into using classnames and a for loop. You will find 90% of your javascript is put into one if condition.

Comment: `CheckboxElement.checked` tests for the boolean value of a checkbox. Obviously, `CheckboxElement.value` is the value of the checkbox. Use conditions and loops. `if(CheckboxElement.checked){someArray.push(CheckboxElement.value)}`. Of course, you would need someArray to be defined. Then you can `.join()` it later or something. Either that or you could just concatenate a String. Your choice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple for-loop saves you.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>HTML and JavaScript</title>
<script>
function doClear()
{
    document.PizzaForm.customer.value ="";
    document.PizzaForm.address.value = "";
    document.PizzaForm.city.value = "";
    document.PizzaForm.state.value="";
    document.PizzaForm.zip.value="";
    document.PizzaForm.phone.value="";
    document.PizzaForm.email.value="";

    document.PizzaForm.sizes[0].checked = false;
    document.PizzaForm.sizes[1].checked = false;
    document.PizzaForm.sizes[2].checked = false;
    document.PizzaForm.sizes[3].checked = false;

    document.PizzaForm.toppings[0].checked = false;
    document.PizzaForm.toppings[1].checked = false;
    document.PizzaForm.toppings[2].checked = false;
    document.PizzaForm.toppings[3].checked = false;
    document.PizzaForm.toppings[4].checked = false;
    document.PizzaForm.toppings[5].checked = false;
    document.PizzaForm.toppings[6].checked = false;
    document.PizzaForm.toppings[7].checked = false;
    document.PizzaForm.toppings[8].checked = false;
    return;
}

function doSubmit()
{
    if(validateText() == true);
    if(validateRadio() == true);
    if(validateCheck() == true);

    var toppings = "";
    for(i=0;i<document.PizzaForm.toppings.length;i++){
        if(document.PizzaForm.toppings[i].checked)
            toppings += (i==0?"":",")+document.PizzaForm.toppings[i].value;
    }
    alert("Name:" + " " + document.PizzaForm.customer.value + 
          '\n' + 
          "Address:" + " " + document.PizzaForm.address.value + 
          '\n' +
          "City:" + " " + document.PizzaForm.city.value +
          '\n' +
          "State:" + " " + document.PizzaForm.state.value +
          '\n' +
          "Zip:" + " " + document.PizzaForm.zip.value +
          '\n' +
          "Phone:" + " " + document.PizzaForm.phone.value +
          '\n' +
          "Email:" + " " + document.PizzaForm.email.value +
          '\n' +
          "Size:" + " " + document.PizzaForm.sizes.value +
          '\n' +
          "Toppings:" + " " + toppings);
    return;
}
function validateText()
{
    var customer = document.PizzaForm.customer.value;
    if (customer.length == 0)
    {
        alert("Please enter your name.")
    }
    var address = document.PizzaForm.address.value;
    if (address.length == 0)
    {
        alert("Please enter an address.")
    }
    var city = document.PizzaForm.city.value;
    if (city.length == 0)
    {
        alert("Please enter a city.")
    }
    var state = document.PizzaForm.state.value;
    if (state.length == 0)
    {
        alert("Please enter a state.")
    }
    var zip = document.PizzaForm.zip.value;
    if (zip.length == 0)
    {
        alert("Please enter a zip code.")
    }
    var phone = document.PizzaForm.phone.value;
    if (phone.length == 0)
    {
        alert("Please enter a phone number.")
    }
    var email = document.PizzaForm.email.value;
        atpos = email.indexOf("@");
        dotpos = email.lastIndexOf(".");
    if (atpos < 1 || ( dotpos - atpos < 2 ))
    {
        alert("Please enter an email address.")
        return false;
    }
        return true;
}

function validateRadio()
{
    if (document.PizzaForm.sizes[0].checked) return true;
    if (document.PizzaForm.sizes[1].checked) return true;
    if (document.PizzaForm.sizes[2].checked) return true;
    if (document.PizzaForm.sizes[3].checked) return true;
    if (document.PizzaForm.sizes.value == false);
    {
        alert("Please choose a pizza size.");
    }
    return;
}

function validateCheck()
{
    if (document.PizzaForm.toppings[0].checked == false &&
        document.PizzaForm.toppings[1].checked == false &&
        document.PizzaForm.toppings[2].checked == false &&
        document.PizzaForm.toppings[3].checked == false &&
        document.PizzaForm.toppings[4].checked == false &&
        document.PizzaForm.toppings[5].checked == false &&
        document.PizzaForm.toppings[6].checked == false &&
        document.PizzaForm.toppings[7].checked == false &&
        document.PizzaForm.toppings[8].checked == false)
        {
            alert("Please pick a topping of your choice.");
        }
            return false;
            return true;
}

</script>
</head>

<body>
<form name="PizzaForm">
<h1>The JavaScript Pizza Parlor</h1>
<p>
<h4>Step 1: Enter your name, address, and phone number:</h4>
<font face ="Courier New">
Name: &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input name="customer" size="50" type="text"><br>
Address: <input name="address" size"50" type="text"><br>
City: &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input name="city" size="15" type="text">
State: <input name="state" size="2" type="TEXT">
Zip: <input name="zip" size="5" type="text"><br>
Phone: &nbsp;&nbsp;<input name="phone" size="50" type="text"><br>
Email: &nbsp;&nbsp;<input name="email" size="40" type="text"><br>
</font>
</p>
<p>
<h4>Step 2: Select the size of pizza you want:</h4>
<font face="Courier New">
<input name="sizes" type="radio" value="Small">Small
<input name="sizes" type="radio" value="Medium">Medium
<input name="sizes" type="radio" value="Large">Large
<input name="sizes" type="radio" value="Jumbo">Jumbo<br>
</font>
</p>
<p>
<h4>Step 3: Select the pizza toppings you want:</h4>
<font face="Courier New">
<input name="toppings" type="checkbox" value="Pepperoni">Pepperoni
<input name="toppings" type="checkbox" value="Canadian Bacon">Canadian Bacon
<input name="toppings" type="checkbox" value="Sausage">Sausage<br>
<input name="toppings" type="checkbox" value="Mushrooms">Mushrooms
<input name="toppings" type="checkbox" value="Pineapple">Pineapple
<input name="toppings" type="checkbox" value="Black Olives">Black Olives<br>
<input name="toppings" type="checkbox" value="Green Peppers">Green Peppers
<input name="toppings" type="checkbox" value="Extra Cheese">Extra Cheese
<input name="toppings" type="checkbox" value="None">None<br>
</font>
</p>
<input type="button" value="Submit Order" onClick="doSubmit()">
<input type="button" value="Clear Entries" onClick="doClear()">
</form>
</body>

</html>
```

The doClear() function is actually unnecessary because you can make the "Clear Entries" button as type="reset" to do the same thing.

Also, after you get familiar with for-loops, you may refine your code as the following:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>HTML and JavaScript</title>
<script>
function doSubmit()
{
    // validate the fields
    if( ! (validateText() && validateRadio() && validateCheck()) ) return false;

    // generate the box message
    var fields=["customer", "address", "city", "state", "zip", "phone", "email","sizes"];
    var fieldNames=["Name", "Address", "City", "State", "Zip", "Phone", "Email","Size"];
    var msg = "";
    for(i=0;i<fields.length;i++)
        msg += fieldNames[i] + ": " + document.PizzaForm[ fields[i] ].value + "\n";
    msg += "Toppings: ";
    for(i=0;i<document.PizzaForm.toppings.length;i++)
        if(document.PizzaForm.toppings[i].checked)
            msg += (i==0?"":",")+document.PizzaForm.toppings[i].value;
    alert(msg);
    return true;
}
function validateText()
{
    var pass=true;
    var fields=["customer", "address", "city", "state", "zip", "phone"];
    var fieldNames=["your name", "an address", "a city", "a state", "a zip code", "a phone number"];
    for(i=0;i<fields.length;i++)
        if(document.PizzaForm[ fields[i] ].value.length == 0){
            alert("Please enter " + fieldNames[i] + ".");
            pass=false;
        }
    var email = document.PizzaForm["email"].value;
    atpos = email.indexOf("@"); dotpos = email.lastIndexOf(".");
    if (atpos < 1 || ( dotpos - atpos < 2 )){alert("Please enter an email address.");pass=false;}
    return pass;
}

function validateRadio()
{
    for(i=0;i<document.PizzaForm.sizes.length;i++)
        if(document.PizzaForm.sizes[i].checked)
            return true;
    alert("Please choose a pizza size.");
    return false;
}

function validateCheck()
{
    for(i=0;i<document.PizzaForm.toppings.length;i++)
        if(document.PizzaForm.toppings[i].checked)
            return true;
    alert("Please pick a topping of your choice.");
    return false;
}

</script>
</head>

<body>
<form name="PizzaForm">
<h1>The JavaScript Pizza Parlor</h1>
<p>
<h4>Step 1: Enter your name, address, and phone number:</h4>
<font face ="Courier New">
Name: &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input name="customer" size="50" type="text"><br>
Address: <input name="address" size"50" type="text"><br>
City: &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input name="city" size="15" type="text">
State: <input name="state" size="2" type="TEXT">
Zip: <input name="zip" size="5" type="text"><br>
Phone: &nbsp;&nbsp;<input name="phone" size="50" type="text"><br>
Email: &nbsp;&nbsp;<input name="email" size="40" type="text"><br>
</font>
</p>
<p>
<h4>Step 2: Select the size of pizza you want:</h4>
<font face="Courier New">
<input name="sizes" type="radio" value="Small">Small
<input name="sizes" type="radio" value="Medium">Medium
<input name="sizes" type="radio" value="Large">Large
<input name="sizes" type="radio" value="Jumbo">Jumbo<br>
</font>
</p>
<p>
<h4>Step 3: Select the pizza toppings you want:</h4>
<font face="Courier New">
<input name="toppings" type="checkbox" value="Pepperoni">Pepperoni
<input name="toppings" type="checkbox" value="Canadian Bacon">Canadian Bacon
<input name="toppings" type="checkbox" value="Sausage">Sausage<br>
<input name="toppings" type="checkbox" value="Mushrooms">Mushrooms
<input name="toppings" type="checkbox" value="Pineapple">Pineapple
<input name="toppings" type="checkbox" value="Black Olives">Black Olives<br>
<input name="toppings" type="checkbox" value="Green Peppers">Green Peppers
<input name="toppings" type="checkbox" value="Extra Cheese">Extra Cheese
<input name="toppings" type="checkbox" value="None">None<br>
</font>
</p>
<input type="button" value="Submit Order" onClick="doSubmit()">
<input type="reset" value="Clear Entries">
</form>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for the help! Are there any good resources where I can read up more on for loops? I really want to have a better understanding of how they work.

Comment: There are tremendously many websites teaching for-loops for beginners. Here is one link to W3schools's tutorial of for-loop: 
http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_loop_for.asp

Comment: I have add a refined version using for-loop, though it may not very elegant, as a suggestion for you.

Comment: Wow! This is really some advanced stuff. I have a lot of work to do if I want to be able to do this kind of coding. Thank you once again!

Comment: Hi Ting Yi Shih, I have an update this program. Would you be able to take a look at it when you get some time? the link to the question is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30582328/use-js-to-display-dropdown-list-and-convert-name-and-city-values-to-uppercase-in the name is also "Use JS to Display Dropdown List and Convert Name and City values to Uppercase In New Window"